# Why isn't the value of the string being fetched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm going through the book *Eloquent Javascript*, and I'm having a bit of trouble on one of the exercises (I'm putting all the exercises on a page, which is not asked of). Basically what it asks for is to create a function that will go through a string, find the number of "B"'s in that string, and return that number. For some reason, It is only returning 0. The function itself is fine, but I'm having trouble finding out what to do to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('#beaninput').val();
    function countBeans(string) {
        var beanCounter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            if (string.charAt(i) == "B") {
                beanCounter += 1;
            };
        };
        return beanCounter;
    };
    $('#beanbutton').click(function() {
        $('#beanbot').empty();
        $('#beanbot').append(countBeans(text) + " Beans");
    });
});
```

As a reference, #beaninput is an HTML text input field, and #beanbutton is a button that should display the number of "B"'s in #beanbot.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks everyone! Works out great.

Comment: You probably need to put `var text = $('#beaninput').val();` inside the `click` handler to get the most up to date value before counting. The way it is now, it'll only ever use  the initial value at page load, which will be blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fetching the value of the text field only once, during the "ready" initialization. It should fetch the value inside the "click" handler.

Move the line that declares that `text` variable to the beginning of the "click" handler for the button.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `text` assignment in `onClick` event handler:

```
$('#beanbutton').click(function() {
    var text = $('#beaninput').val();
    $('#beanbot').empty();
    $('#beanbot').append(countBeans(text) + " Beans");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `var text = $('#beaninput').val();` to the `.click` function, otherwise its value will be always`0`,  i.e.:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function countBeans(string) {
        var beanCounter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            if (string.charAt(i) == "B") {
                beanCounter += 1;
            };
        };
        return beanCounter;
    };
    $('#beanbutton').click(function() {
         var text = $('#beaninput').val();
        $('#beanbot').empty();
        $('#beanbot').append(countBeans(text) + " Beans");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="beaninput">
<button id="beanbutton"> GO </button>
<p id="beanbot"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The input value is empty at the time the DOM-ready (`DOMContentLoaded`) event fires.
You should read the value at the point where you want to process it instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#beans').on("input", function() {
    var bees = this.value.match(/b/gi);
    $('output').val(bees ? bees.length : 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="beans" />
<output></output>
```

This solution uses [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (Regex)